# Select two different columns from the same row using two different queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to run two queries at a time in a function to verify the username and email separately when registering. If one of them already exists in the database, it will return the correct error message on the form.
I investigate them separately so that they can be linked to two separate messages based on a query.
If the username already exists in the database, display the corresponding message. If I put them in a single query, then the separate investigation cannot be done.

My error is: It does not allow you to run two queries at the same time and throws the following error: there is a problem with the preceding parameter. Or it returns an incorrect value.

```
function pl($connection) {
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $query2 = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";

    if ($statment = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query) && $statment2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query2)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statment, "s", $_POST['usern']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statment);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statment);
        $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statment2, "s", $_POST['email']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statment2);
        $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statment2);
        $record2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    }
    if ($result != null) {
        echo "succes";
        //it will enter even if there is an error
    }
}
```

How it could be solved to execute two `mysqli_prepare()` at a time?

Comment: "it will enter even if there is an error" is rather a dangerous misconception. When there is an error, the code doesт't have to enter anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use one query?
Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = ? and email = ?";
$statment = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statment, "ss", $_POST['usern'], $_POST['email']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statment);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statment);
$record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (!$record) {
    echo "succes";
    //it will enter even if there is an error
}
```

also you miss the `}` at end of your first `if`

Comment: `$result != null` is rather incorrect. It should be either `!$result` or if you want to be more pious than the Pope, then `$result !== false`

Comment: oh, and the first `if` is absolutely useless if not harmful

Comment: Thank you! And I also missed that it should be $record, not $result. Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure, but I think OP was looking for OR comparison. If either email or username is taken then it should not allow to add new record.